Select a different email address from my mail in Outlook
I created a working email sending macro.
I have three email addresses to select in the "From" box. I want to select one of the email addresses.
Sub enviar_email()

Set objeto_outlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

Set Email = objeto_outlook.CreateItem(0)

Email.Display

Email.To = Cells(2, 1).ValueEmail.cc = ""Email.bcc = ""Email.Subject = "Hello Teste"Email.Body = Cells(2, 2).Value & "," & Chr(10) & Chr(10) _

Cells(2, 3).Value & Chr(10) & Chr(10) _& "Thanks" & Chr(10) & "Regards"

Email.Attachments.Add (ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Marcelo - " & Cells(2, 4).Value & ".xlsm")

End sub


To select a specific "From" email in your Outlook macro, you can set the SentOnBehalfOfName property of the mail item to the desired email address:
Sub SendEmailWithFromAddress()
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim fromAddress As String

    ' Set the "From" address (replace with your specific email address)
    fromAddress = "your.email@domain.com"

    ' Create the Outlook application and mail item
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    With OutMail
        ' Set the "From" address
        .SentOnBehalfOfName = fromAddress


If you want to send as an Exchange user that you can send on behalf of, set the MailItem.SentOnBehalfOfName property to the name of that Exchange mailbox.
If you want to send through a separate account (POP3/SMTP, etc.), set the MailItem.Account property to an account from the Application.Session.Accounts collection.
